# How to pass search results to the controller

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The HTML page displays search results . On click of Mass update button, I need to pass the search results(`searchList`) to the controller. Can anyone help on how to pass the whole search result to the controller? The result is of the type `List<Map<String, Object>>`

HTML Code:

```
<div id="resultstabJoin" th:if="!${#lists.isEmpty(searchList)}"> 
    <table class="tg" id="results" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th class="">Person #</th> 
                <th class="">Creator</th> 
                <th class="">Valid From</th>
                <th class="">Valid To</th>
                <th class="">Effective From</th>
                <th class="">Expiry</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="map : ${searchList}"> 
                <td class="tg bg"><a th:id="${map['PERSON_ID']}" style="cursor: pointer;"
                    th:text="${map['PERSON_ID']}"                                   
                    th:onclick="'javascript:viewActionURL(\'' + @{../searchController/__${map['PERSON_ID']}__} + '\')'"></a></td>   
                <td class="tg bg" th:text="${map['CREATED_BY']}"></td>
                <td class="tg bg" th:text="${map['VALID_FROM']}"></td>
                <td class="tg bg" th:text="${map['VALID_TO']}"></td>
                <td class="tg bg" th:text="${map['COMMENCEMENT_DT']}"></td>
                <td class="tg bg" th:text="${map['EXPIRY_DT']}"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="row" align="right" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">  
        <input type="button" value="Mass Update" class="btn btn-primary" id="massUpdate"  th:onclick="'javascript:muActionURL(\'' + @{/searchController/massUpdate} +  '\')'"/>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert searchlist to JSON: var searchListJson = JSON.stringify(searchList)
2. When user clicks the update button, submit a form where the searchListJson is set to a hidden input field

Answer (score 0):

Since your search results appear to be coming from the same app that the mass update button interacts with, you don't need to request the data and then push it back.  Simply make a request that triggers an update on the server using the same lookup strategy as your search results.  This avoids sending potentially large datasets back and forth unnecessarily.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I am sorry. I dont understand clearly. Can I ask you to explain in detail. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is, search results will be displayed on click of search button. But later, when mass update button is clicked, search results is getting vanished. I need to retain the result table. As per the code, search button action goes to `/search` mapping of the controller, and mass update button click redirects to `/massupdate` mapping of the controller. The result is actually being fetched from DB and set in modelAttribute which is handles and set in `/search`